# Sort DocumentSnapshort error List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' of 'iterable'

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to sort DocumentSnapshot from Firebase. I found the error when InsertAll to List shows List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' of 'iterable'

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried to search problem but didn't fix it. Please advise where I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

```
static List<DocumentSnapshot> sortDocumentsByComment(List<DocumentSnapshot> data){
List<DocumentSnapshot> _originalData = data;
Map<String,List<DocumentSnapshot>> commentDocuments = <String,List<DocumentSnapshot>>{};
List<int> replyCommentIndex = [];
for(int i = 0; i < _originalData.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < _originalData.length; j++){
    if (_originalData[i]['commentID'] == _originalData[j]['toCommentID']){
      List<DocumentSnapshot>? savedCommentData;
      if (commentDocuments[_originalData[i]['commentID']] != null ){
        savedCommentData = commentDocuments[_originalData[i]['commentID']];
      }else {
        savedCommentData = [];
      }
      savedCommentData?.add(_originalData[j]);
      commentDocuments[_originalData[i]['commentID']] = savedCommentData!;
      replyCommentIndex.add(j);
    }
  }
}

replyCommentIndex.sort((a,b){
  return b.compareTo(a);
});

if(replyCommentIndex.length > 0){

  for(int i = 0; i < replyCommentIndex.length; i++){
    _originalData.removeAt(replyCommentIndex[i]);
  }
}

for(int i = 0; i < _originalData.length; i++){

  if (commentDocuments[_originalData[i]['commentID']] != null){
    _originalData.insertAll(i+1,commentDocuments[_originalData[i]['commentID']]!);
  }
}
return _originalData;
```

}

Comment: Add .toList() to what you're sorting.  You can't sort an Iterable, only a List.

Comment: I try to add .toList but it doesn't work.